# How does Xcode decide what to put into its 'Attach to Process' menu?

Tags: python, xcode, debugging, gdb, distutils

Xcode makes a guess at the proccess you may want to attach to in your gdb session. It always guesses wrong and I have to look up the process ID (it's a Python module) and type it in myself. Annoying.

How does Xcode build this menu? Is there any way to hint that the Python process is the one I want?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 14 displays several different groups:

- Likely
- Application
- System

I couldn't find official Apple Xcode docs, but this article was informative.

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/connecting-xcode-to-a-running-process/

I'm not sure that it is intended to debug Python, so finding it in such a long menu is going to be problematic (unless you want to get wild as the admin and rename it to something else that sorts higher).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The question was from 12 years ago, Xcode is probably unrecognisably different now! I think at the time I was debugging a C shared library that was loaded as a CPython module.

Comment: The fringes remain as mysterious as ever. I'm starting a pile of new projects, so I've decided to front load looking at these things.